# Why can't I populate my controller with items?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using an ItemController to provide a list of items to use in a tableview. I can't seem to populate the controller though, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the code for the controller class:

**.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Item;

@interface ItemController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *items;

- (NSUInteger)countOfList;
- (Item*)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex;
- (void)addItem:(Item *)item;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "ItemController.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface ItemController ()
@end

@implementation ItemController

- (NSUInteger)countOfList {
    return [self.items count];
}
- (Item *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {
    return [self.items objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

- (void)addItem:(Item *)item {
    [self.items addObject:item];
}

@end
```

**Item.m**

```
@implementation Item

-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

I'm using the following code to populate the list:

```
ItemController* controller = [[ItemController alloc] init];
for (NSString* key in raw_data) {
    NSLog(key); // This outputs the keys fine
    [controller addItem:[[Item alloc] initWithName:key]];
}
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[controller countOfList]]); // Always 0
```

Comment: can you share the Item class as well ? 
What does your initWithName really doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your variable `items`. In your init method, call `self.items = [NSMutableArray new];` and also change your array property from `copy` to `retain`.

I also believe your class `ItemController` should be of kind `UIViewController` and not `NSObject`.

`@interface ItemController : UIViewController`

Comment: Thanks, this sorted the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array in the init methond.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`, seems adding objects to the controller is breaking it.

Comment: may be you are missing @synthesize for items?

Comment: also put a log in init for [self.items class], because your array is immutable now

Comment: @Stas That line throws an exception. Maybe I'm approaching this entirely the wrong way. I just want to display a bunch of items I've got via JSON in a tableview. Why is this so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialise the `_items` instance variable anywhere, so it's always `nil`. The result of any integer-returning method called on `nil` will be 0, so you see that the count is 0.